# Hosting specification for ASP.NET Online Image Editor

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web, shared-hosting

I intent to create an Online image editor like [pixlr.com/editor](http://pixlr.com/editor). I want to use ASP.NET as the P-language and so prefer windows hosting.What should i look for like Bandwidth,Space,Database etc.I wonder how many concurrent users can use the site(with/without db connection).

Answer (score 0):

Appharbor is a great, freemium source. You submit files via git or Github, BitBucket, or Codeplex. It is basically Heroku for .NET. For free you get unlimited commits and space (I think), the bandwidth is great, and it is fast enough. You get a .apphb.com domain. For more information, go to http://www.appharbor.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of Windows Azure for applications - it's start price (round $15 per month) is affordable and it has the benifit of being scalable.

pretty sure it also comes with a 3 month free trial - worth a go.

[www.windowsazure.com](http://www.windowsazure.com)